# Word for a person who brings a guest

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Alice is throwing a party.  She invites Bob to come to the party, and says he may bring another person with him.  Bob arrives at the party accompanied by Carol.  We could say Carol is Bob's *guest*.

What's the reverse of this relationship?  Bob is Carol's _______.

Usually *host* is the reverse of *guest*, but that doesn't seem to fit here.  As Alice is throwing the party, *Carol's host* would seem to refer to Alice, not Bob.

*Escort* could work but sounds overly formal, and moreover it seems to me that it carries connotations about Bob's relationship to Carol.

If possible, the term should:

- be gender-neutral (so that it also works if Doris arrives accompanied by Edward, or Frances arrives accompanied by Glinda)
- not carry connotations about any relationship between Bob and Carol (e.g. it should not imply that they are friends, spouses, in a romantic relationship, etc.)
- make it clear that Bob, not Carol, is the person originally invited by Alice.

Comment: "Escort" only carries connotations because of its use as a euphemism for "prostitute".

Comment: i suggest 'pimp'

Comment: As one who always assumes that decorum prevails where there is no evidence to the contrary, I would suggest Bob is Carol's *patron*.

Comment: Perhaps *companion*. But, they are both companions. There is *inviter* but it doesn't sound natural for this context. The usual way is using a word that denotes the relationship between them. By the way, Carol can be called *plus one* also.

Comment: Meal ticket - which is kind of crass, but maybe "Bob is Carol's ticket to the event" would be better and less rude-sounding. :-)

Comment: @KristinaLopez- I was just typing, "Bob is Carol's ticket in [to the event]"

Comment: @ermanen - Of course, "companion" similarly suffers from its use as a euphemism.

Comment: @WS2 - Even employing full decorum, "patron" implies that Carol is getting something from Bob other than a ride to the party.

Comment: It is only fitting to give @ermanen a +1 for "plus one".

Comment: How about a *guest-bringer*? :)  It is rare but [not non-existent](https://novelgobblers.wordpress.com/members-2/etiquette/attending-a-meeting/).

Comment: @HotLicks: Softening "escort" to "escorted by" would solve the connotation problem, yes?

Comment: If you're careful to specify that Carol is *Bob's* guest, while Bob is Alice's guest, the one term could serve for both.

Comment: How about **chaperone**?

Comment: I give up on finding a word that meets all three criteria.  I would use "associate" even though that doesn't describe who invited who.

Comment: @HotLicks I was only speaking half-in-jest when I suggested *patron*. Clearly there is no word that fits - certainly not *chaperone* unless Carol is about 16 and Bob's her older brother. Why should there be a word? Don't people have powers of description? Far too many things are given 'names', in my opinion. And naming things only creates institutions of them!

Comment: @WS2 There may well be no word that 'fits' but I think *chaperone* sounds better in that there are no 'negative connotations' associated with it. Personally, I believe *companion* and *escort* are harmless too and that a negative connotation only applies when you use it in a sexual context.

Comment: I would say "escort" is perfectly fine when the context of a party has already been established.

Answer (score 6):

### *chaperone*

*noun*

1. a person who accompanies and looks after another person or group of people.
   *synonyms*: supervisor, companion, duenna, escort, minder, den mother

> "Bob chaperoned Carol to Alice's party"

Comment: The connotation of "chaperone" is that Carol needs supervision, perhaps even implying that Carol was the one invited but Bob was sent along to make sure she didn't get into trouble. It doesn't seem completely wrong, but I'd be wary of using it, given that connotation.

Comment: It [seems to be relatively more popular than the other alternatives](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YOPu8.png) in TV history. This might be interesting: [Bookworm](http://tiny.cc/bookworm)

Comment: While interesting, that only shows it is a more commonly used word, not whether it is appropriate for this context. For example, the word "victor" is more popular than any of the suggestions, but it doesn't match the request at all.

Comment: I didn't say it was more appropriate, just more popular :) And I downloaded a few random subtitles containing the word and most of them didn't use "chaperone" to mean supervise a woman, although some did.

Comment: Chaperone explicitly "[carries connotations about a guardian (*one who looks after another*) type relationship of Bob over Carol]"

Comment: I would say it is appropriate - even if Carol is an independent and responsible person it still does not demand a demeaning connotation in this context. Bob invited Carol and therefore he is indirectly responsible for her actions and presence at the party whether they are good, bad or neutral. Bob is responsible for informing Carol about any requirements for attending the party, whether it be bringing food, a gift, how to dress, or even perhaps simply being aware of the people at the party and their customs in order to help Carol not offend in ignorance. Therefore, Bob is Carol's chaperone.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't like any of the definitions I found. May it suffice to say he is her *ticket in*:

> Bob is Carol's **voucher**.

Comment: Ticket, meal-ticket, and voucher seem the closest fit. Maybe add some definitions as support?

Comment: Also, ***Attendant***, but again no definition suits me. The synonyms do however: *escort, companion, guard, guide*. -[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/attendant)

Answer (score 0):

## ***invitee***

...is adequate to indicate the person who is actually *invited*, as in "invitees should ensure that their plus ones obey the rules". It does not specify the relationship though...

Answer (score 0):

**guest-bringer**

This is just a word I made up, a combination of *guest* and *bringer*.